# Temporary disable or modify SELinux on Android

Tags: android, selinux

I'm the developer on a **root**-app for Android.

Sadly now on some devices/ROMs there is **SELinux** in *enforce*-mode and prevents some actions of my app.

Because this is a root-app, the users are granting me root-access!

Now, SELinux is blocking some of my actions and I need to find a solution for this.

I tried to temporary disable SELinux by

```
setenforce permissive -> no failure, but getenforce still returns "Enforcing"
echo 0 > /sys/fs/selinux/enforce -> no failure, but getenforce still returns "Enforcing"
```

I play with the idea to edit the **sepolicy**-file at runtime to allow the blocked commands and trigger a reload of it, but I'm neither sure if & how this could work, nor isn't it a good idea.

Who has some more tips or resources for me?

Comment: I thought the su daemon got around SELinux, as well as nosuid, by running in a different context entirely, no? What actions in particular are being blocked?

Comment: I don't know how Chainfire did it with the SU. But in my case it's eg. `avc:  denied  { execstack } for  pid=10971` and maybe more things after that :/

Comment: Are you shipping `execstack` yourself? You do realize that whoever set up Enforcing mode might have locked down the `su` daemon/program till it's helpless in this case, right?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with all those stuff, but SU is working on my device :)

Comment: What exactly are you running with su? It appears that something is running `execstack` (a fairly obscure piece of Linux history) and SELinux is stopping it. Post the full log, please. Does whatever you're running work from the shell?

Comment: Hello Delyan, it's a large piece of code which is not written by me. It injects a shared-library via PTRACE into a running process. Therefor it's changing the stack of the target-process to trigger a dlopen of the shared-library. The ptrace itself works, but then the target-process is crashing due to an SEGV_ACCERR which is (I think) triggered by SELinux and the denied execstack. But really, it's over my knowledge what exactly happens.

Comment: It's the `execstack` call (to make the stack in the binary executable) that fails due to the SE policy. Sorry but this is too niche for me to help.

Comment: Alright, but many thanks for taking the time :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`supolicy`](https://su.chainfire.eu/#selinux-policies) from the SuperSU app, see the link for a detailed description when and how it may be called.

In short:

- Find out why something is blocked by SELinux by checking the audit messages, e.g. `dmesg | grep "audit"`
- Create an `allow ...` rule that allows the blocked operation. They are similar (identical?) to 'allow' rules in SELinux *.te files.
- Run `supolicy --live "allow ..."` in a root shell and check if the operation now succeeds. If not, extend your 'allow' rule(s). You can specify multiple 'allow' rules in a single `supolicy` call.

Note that `supolicy` is an expensive operation, so be sure to call it only once.

If you don't want to depend on Chainfire's SuperSU you may try [`sepolicy-inject`](https://github.com/xmikos/setools-android). I did not test that myself.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I would recommend you to expand on your answer in order to be more helpful and to attract more votes.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added a rough description how to use `supolicy`.

Comment: I'd rather not trust root with a closed source binary, so I don't have SuperSU. I'd love to see what API calls that app is making. I'll try `setpolicy-inject` though.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to disable SELinux on Android 4.3 for a while now and this is what i came up with.

On Samsung S4 Android 4.3, `setenforce 0`  will change to `Permissive` mode.

On Samsung Note 3 Android 4.3, `setenforce 0`  will NOT change SELinux status.

I have tried Nexus 4 Android 4.3, however by default it is `Permissive` mode

Comment: You don't actually answer the question …

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs he didn't? He gave a way to actively change SELinux enforcement at runtime. The OP suggested his issue was directly tied to this. I can confirm that the SELinux status will change when `setenforce` is run as root in CyanogenMod 11.

Answer (score 2):

Edit `build.prop` file in the system folder on root (the very first directory), using a text editor search `selinux`

If you see something like `enable_selinux=1` , change it to `0` , if it is to disable do it vice versa

changes will be applied after a reboot or a boot.

Similarly you can turn on / off multi user account, System updates. My devices manufacturer disabled System Updates.

Comment: In my device, it was set like this `ro.buid.selinux = 1`

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access, run `su 0 setenforce 0` to change to `Permissive` mode:

```
// Set SELinux to permissive
private static final String COMMAND = "su 0 setenforce 0"; 
try {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(COMMAND);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi t1mz0r, thanks for the feedback. That's what I already did and mentioned in my initial request. user1546570 pointed out, that it sometimes works and sometimes not. Meanwhile I know it's not working on a few Samsung-devices. I curcimvented that issue here by programatically changing the policies at runtime and force them to be reloaded, instead of disabling the whole SELinux via setenforce. Now as Android 5 is on the roads, this might in general change - setenforce is at least working for the Nexus-devices. Cheers & kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can download the app name selinux mod changer. It's not on play store so you have download it from chrome or any other browser of your choice. App just need root permission so try it.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
androidboot.selinux=permissive
```

to your kernel boot arguments

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable SElinux and make the entire system `permissive`, you need to change the `selinux.cpp` functions located at `system/core/init`. Two functions `StatusFromProperty()` and `IsEnforcing()` set the status of the SElinux which are called in different units. If you change the value of return for both as `SELINUX_PERMISSIVE` and `false`, the SElinux status always will be permissive. You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77497503/producing-a-user-build-of-aosp-with-permissive-selinux-policy).